# Enable C++14 Intel Compiler

Tags: c++, intel, c++14

I'm using Intel C++ Compiler version 15.0.0.108 Build 20140726 and I can't use some C++14 features like "decltype(auto), return type deduction for normal functions" declared support in [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/c14-features-supported-by-intel-c-compiler)

If I do something like:

```
std::for_each(vector.begin(), vector.end(), [] (auto value) {});
```

Then I got this error:

> error: "auto" is not allowed here

I'm compiling using this:

```
icl /FA /EHs program.cpp
```

Comment: No option for the language-standard?

Comment: I read the entire help from the command line and tried to find on Google and nothing. The help from command line has an option called `/Qstd=<std>` but only with `c++11` or `c++0x`, I tried `c++14` and `c++1y` and doesn't work. It says: invalid argument for option '/Qstd'.

Comment: Huh - the link in your own question says Intel just does not support this...

Comment: I think you might have your C++14 features mixed up. You're not using return type deduction or `decltype(auto)`. The feature you're trying to use is *Generic lambda expressions* and they don't support it yet.

Comment: Oh gosh, that is a shame. - Thank you guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature you're trying to use is called a generic (polymorphic) lambda expression from [N3649](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3649.html) and the [table](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/c14-features-supported-by-intel-c-compiler) you linked shows that support has not been added yet. However, the feature(s) you *think* you're using, "decltype(auto), return type deduction for normal functions" from [N3638](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3638.html) do have support.

A generic lambda looks like:

```
[](auto a) { return a; }
```

Return type deduction for normal functions looks like:

```
auto func() { return 42; } // deduced to be int
```

The semantics for `decltype(auto)` are described in the following example from n3638:

> If the placeholder is the decltype(auto) type-specifier, the declared
>   type of the variable or return type of the function shall be the
>   placeholder alone. The type deduced for the variable or return type is
>   determined as described in 7.1.6.2, as though the initializer had been
>   the operand of the decltype. [ Example:
>
> ```
> int i;
> int&& f();
> auto           x3a = i;        // decltype(x3a) is int
> decltype(auto) x3d = i;        // decltype(x3d) is int
> auto           x4a = (i);      // decltype(x4a) is int
> decltype(auto) x4d = (i);      // decltype(x4d) is int&
> auto           x5a = f();      // decltype(x5a) is int
> decltype(auto) x5d = f();      // decltype(x5d) is int&&
> auto           x6a = { 1, 2 }; // decltype(x6a) is std::initializer_list<int>
> decltype(auto) x6d = { 1, 2 }; // error, { 1, 2 } is not an expression
> auto          *x7a = &i;       // decltype(x7a) is int*
> decltype(auto)*x7d = &i;       // error, declared type is not plain decltype(auto)
> ```
>
> — end example ]